# What is the type of `async let` declaration in Swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, static-typing

Swift 5.5 introduces coroutines, hierarchical task management and function suspension.
One of the new features is a syntax of

```
async let image = downloadImage(url)
```

The declaration of image can be `await`'ed. But the question is, what is its type? What does the Xcode say its type is? What type can I declare for a function parameter to accept this object?

Comment: Good question. As you’ll see when you try it out, Xcode will just report that it is declared as `async let image: UIImage`. And the Xcode variables inspector will just say that it is a `UIImage`. There is no generic wrapper type, like we’re used to seeing in Combine types. But it’s not just a simple `UIImage`, either, as you can’t just use it without adorning the subsequent references with `await` (or, as is likely the case here, `try await`).

Comment: FWIW, if you're looking for the terminology, the _type_ of the variable, `image`, is a `UIImage`, but behind the scenes, the compiler will create a _task_ for it, namely an “async-let binding” task. See [Explore structured concurrency in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10134/?time=241).

Comment: @Rob Yep, thank you, I figured as much! But - here's a question... How could one pass an instantiated `async let` into a function tho! Have not been able to figure this one out yet other than via an obvious "async closure" approach...

Comment: You usually would just `await` (or `try await`) it when you supply it as a parameter to that function.

Comment: Then it resolves before the function is called instead of waiting until it is used in some await inside the function. Getting clever and trying to pass an async closure doesn't work either: https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/57957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the question is, what is its type?

That question is settled in the same way as *any* variable declaration with initialization: by the type of what's on the right-hand side of the equal sign.

For example, if you have a method that returns a String (let's name it `getMyString`), then when you say

```
let s = getMyString()
```

...`s` is typed as String, inferred from the return type of the called method.

Well, it's no different with `async let`:

```
async let s = getMyString()
```

If `getMyString` returns a String, `s` will be a String.

The only difference is that, *ex hypothesi*, that String is returned *asynchronously*. But that makes no difference to the overall syntax here. That is the whole *point* of `async/await`; it lets you call code asynchronously within the realm of normal Swift syntax (instead of having to dance round the moon with GCD closures).

Comment: Alright, so this means syntactically that inspecting this member at this point displays the overall result-in-future of the Task, and not the underlying type such as `Task<UIImage>`, `Future<UIImage>`, etc. Thank you for checking

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many other programming languages, Swift's concurrency model does not use a `Future`, `Promise` or similar type at all.
An expression either needs to be `await`ed or it doesn't.

Therefore, something that would work with async/await implementations in other programming languages (e.g. JavaScript) won't work in Swift:

```swift
func test() async {
    let a = getNumber() // error: Expression is 'async' but is not marked with 'await'
    print(await a) // warning: No 'async' operations occur within 'await' expression
}

func getNumber() async -> Int {
    42
}
```

This is one of the reasons for the `async let` syntax: it allows you call an async function but defer the `await`ing until a later point.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the kind of point I was trying address for myself - why is the underlying metaphysical type of a Task is not exposed for the programmer in the way it's done in ECMAScript...

Comment: @IsaaсWeisberg It's all about efficiency/performance I believe. Doug Gregor goes into some detail about the design in this podcast episode: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/podcast/99/